# Como extrair dados de uma lista de uma única coluna e gerar outra?

Tags: python

Bom dia. Sou novo na programação e comecei por curiosidade e necessidade de eliminar algumas funções repetitivas do meu dia a dia.

Estou criando um código que entra em um equipamento de rede (biblioteca netmiko), dá um comando e pega o retorno dele.
O output é algo similar com o apresentado abaixo, sempre vem 1 linha com 'Underlying Interface: ' e outra com 'Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.'.

**1 -** O que tentei e não estou conseguindo é eliminar estas palavras deixando apenas 'xe-1/0/6' e '2847' para todas as linhas. Quando executei dois if separados, eu consegui eliminar as palavras deixando só o que quero, mas apenas para a primeira aparição.

Tentei fazer com um for, mas não consigo obter uma resposta.

**2 -** Após conseguir fazer o passo 1, preciso organizar os dados em coluna 1 (todas as aparições que tenham xe - linhas ímpares) e coluna 2 ( todas aparições que tenham os 4 últimos números ex:2847 - linhas pares)

output retorna essa lista que pode ter 500 linhas ou até 120 mil:
output=
Underlying Interface: xe-1/0/6
Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.2847
Underlying Interface: xe-1/0/7
Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.2842
Underlying Interface: xe-1/0/9
Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.2862

```
output = connection.send_command(command)

for p in range(0, len(output), 1):
     if '0x8100.' in output[p]:
         vlan = output[p]
         vlan = vlan[vlan.find('0x8100')+7:vlan.find('0x8100')+11]
         print(vlan)

     if 'Interface' in output[p]:
        interface = output[p]
        interface = interface[interface.find('Interface') + 11:interface.find('Interface') + 19]
        print(interface)
```

resultado final que estou buscando:
xe-1/0/6 2847
xe-1/0/7 2842
xe-1/0/9 2862

---

Edit 1: A resposta trás apenas a primeira aparição: [['xe-1/0/6'], ['2847']]
Os dados ouput sao obtidos da resposta de um equipamento de rede, desta forma forcei eles em string e coloquei numa lista. Abaixo segue o código apenas ocultando os dados do equipamento e senha.
Lista completa output: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12qq5P0DqFWheCDuNW6wTP4M7qkjT1HtV

```
import netmiko
import time

start = time.time()

connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip='100.100.100.100',device_type='juniper_junos',username='teste',password='teste')
command = 'show subscribers client-type vlan detail | match "^Underlying Interface\:|^Stacked VLAN Id"'

outputA = connection.send_command(command)
outputB = str(outputA)
output = [outputA]

connection.disconnect()

result = [[], []]
for p in range(len(output)):
    if '0x8100.' in output[p]:
        result[1].append(output[p][output[p].find('0x8100')+ 7 : output[p].find('0x8100') + 11])
    if 'Interface' in output[p]:
        result[0].append(output[p][output[p].find('Interface') + 11 : output[p].find('Interface') + 19])

print(result)

end = time.time()
print('Tempo de execução: {} segundos'.format((end - start)))
```

Resposta do python: [['xe-1/0/6'], ['2847']]
Tempo de execução: 6.372122049331665 segundos

---

Edit 2 - print mostrando a classe do outputA e o print de outputA
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui chegar a esse código para o seu problema:

```
result = [[], []]
for p in range(len(output)):
    if '0x8100.' in output[p]:
        result[1].append(output[p][output[p].find('0x8100')+ 7 : output[p].find('0x8100') + 11])
    if 'Interface' in output[p]:
        result[0].append(output[p][output[p].find('Interface') + 11 : output[p].find('Interface') + 19])

print(result)
```

1. Você estava atribuindo a string "limpa" sempre a uma mesma variável, então a cada iteração você apagava o valor antigo e colocava um novo no lugar. Então para armazenar todos os valores, você deve colocar isso numa lista. O método `append()` de listas, adiciona o valor que você passa pra ele no final da lista.
2. Já que você precisa de duas "colunas", da pra usar uma lista que contenha 2 outras listas dentro, uma para a coluna 1 e outra para a coluna 2. Para acessar um valor, você usa por exemplo: `result[0][0]`, ( valor da primeira linha e primeira coluna).

EDIT 1:

Visto que o retorno da função `connection` é uma string enorme, então você precisa quebrá-la em uma lista, para o método que eu sugeri funcionar.
Acredito que você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
outputA = connection.send_command(command)
output = outputA.split('\n')
```

Usando o método `split` no `outputA`, com o parâmetro de separador `\n`, você quebra a string nas "quebras de linha", te retornando uma lista com cada linha. Daí você pode passar o `output` para o código que eu indiquei. Espero que dê certo dessa vez.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado.
Tentei aqui e ainda não deu certo, mas vou estudar passo a passo do que você falou e continuar tentando. Já me deu um norte enorme, principalmente sobre o fato de estar limpando a variável no for.

Comment: Pra esse código, eu assumi que a variável output é da classe list, e ela contém strings, conforme os dados que você informou, você pode confirmar isso por favor? E qual foi o erro que ocorreu dessa vez?

Comment: Leonardo, fiz o Edit 1 no texto com os detalhes e com o código completo, output completo também. Agradeço novamente.

Comment: Olha, aqui eu não consigo rodar essa parte do netmiko, mas notei que a sua variavel output recebe outputA, ao invés de outputB, que seria a string, além disso não estou completamente certo quanto a essa "conversão" para lista, você deveria usar a função list(outputB). Faz o seguinte, lê os dados a partir do netmiko na variável outputA, e  usa print(type(outputA)), e me diz qual o tipo dessa variável.

Comment: a classe do output dele é uma lista, ele declara quando converte o outputA, o problema é que ele não passou os elementos do outputA por um loop para depois popular uma lista ai queria saber se a conversão não foi defeituosa, se não foi é só ele pegar o output e passar como parâmetro para minha função que já resolve o problema

Comment: Sobre seu teste leonardo, o retorno: <class 'str'>
Estou entendendo o código do Jefferson agora.

Comment: Então a função connection está de retornando uma string? Você precisa quebrar essa string em uma lista, para então poder passar para as funções de separação. Por favor atualiza sua pergunta, coloca um screenshot do print(outputA). Pra a partir do formato dessa string, a gente tentar quebrar ela na lista que você precisa.

Comment: Leonardo fiz o edit 2 com o Print.

O código disponibilizado pelo Jeferson para um output genérico não está trazendo retorno, ainda estou entendendo e testando algumas coisas para tentar ajustar (vou levar um pouco de tempo).

Comment: Vou fazer um Edit na minha resposta, acho que entendi o problema. É que seu retorno é uma única string, com várias linhas.

Comment: Leonardo, deu tudo certo.
Já criei um dataframe com as duas colunas e vou trabalhar em cima delas.
Agradeço muitíssimo você e o Jefferson pelo apoio. Só não consigo dar voto ainda nas respostas por falta de reputação, mas assim que conseguir vou dar o feedback.
Agora vou estudar os códigos de vocês dois para entender melhor o passo a passo.

Comment: Top, qualquer dúvida pode chamar aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, primeiramente seja bem-vindo.

Gostaria de aconselhar que na próxima vez que for fazer uma pergunte deixe todo o código fonte que você está utilizando pois seria melhor de auxiliar sabendo totalmente do que se trata, vou tentar ajudar do jeito que eu posso com as informações que você nos passou.

Você ira precisar de fazer uma alteração importante no seu código, tente rodar o código abaixo a partir do seu código original o primeiro postado com essas modificações.

```
output = connection.send_command(command)

listaObjetos = []

for i in output:
    listaObjetos.append(i)

def categorizar(outputList):
    UnderlyingList = []
    StackedList = []
    joinList = []
    for Under in outputList:
        if 'Underlying' in Under:
            UnderlyingList.append(Under.replace('Underlying Interface: ', ''))
        else:
            pass
    for Stacked in outputList:
        if 'Stacked' in Stacked:
            StackedList.append(Stacked.replace('Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.', ''))
        else:
            pass
    for count in range(len(UnderlyingList)):
        joinList.append('{} {}'.format(UnderlyingList[count], StackedList[count]))
    return joinList

for item in categorizar(listaObjetos):
    print(item)
```

Como não tenho acesso ao output original eu fiz uma simulação mas você deverá pegar a o output e adicionar cada item direto a uma lista SEM PROCESSAR NADA.

Testei o código simulando seu output em forma de lista e funcionou:

```
output = ['Underlying Interface: xe-1/0/6', 'Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.2847', 
            'Underlying Interface: xe-1/0/7', 'Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.2842', 
            'Underlying Interface: xe-1/0/9', 'Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.2862']

def categorizar(outputList):
    UnderlyingList = []
    StackedList = []
    joinList = []
    for Under in outputList:
        if 'Underlying' in Under:
            UnderlyingList.append(Under.replace('Underlying Interface: ', ''))
        else:
            pass
    for Stacked in outputList:
        if 'Stacked' in Stacked:
            StackedList.append(Stacked.replace('Stacked VLAN Id: 0x8100.', ''))
        else:
            pass
    for count in range(len(UnderlyingList)):
        joinList.append('{} {}'.format(UnderlyingList[count], StackedList[count]))
    return joinList

for item in categorizar(output):
    print(item)
```

o meu output foi:

```
xe-1/0/6 2847
xe-1/0/7 2842
xe-1/0/9 2862
```

Comment: Jefferson, boa tarde.
Agradeço pelo apoio. Eu até fiz um edit (Edit 1) uns 40 minutos atrás expondo todo o código e a lista completa do output (fui me tocar um pouco tarde). Irei estudar o código para entender passo a passo o que passou e testar o código, assim que eu tiver novidades retorno aqui.